# Sorting by nearest locations in Backand?

Tags: geolocation, geopoints, backand

Is it possible to sort returned objects from Backand based on how near the location field of type "point" is to the querying users current location?

From the Backand docs I have only seen support for querying based on a maximum distance from a point but nothing about sorting by geo points.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a custom query in Backand which I can hit from the Backand API. Unfortunately in order to sort on the distance of nearby users I need to calculate the distance from the current user to every other user in the database and then sort based on this. Seems very complex - a lot of calculations every time the query is called! Will probably see big performance hits as the database gets larger. Guess it answers this question, but I am hopeful still of finding a better alternative.

Comment: It seems like you might be in need of a graphing algorithm and memoization, which can reduce the amount of time you spend calculating each of these distances at the expense of increasing your data storage costs.

Another option would be to return the distance to a particular user as a field in the query. If you check on the distance squared instead of the distance, you can cut the operations needed down to two multiplications and an add for each user in the DB. The problem is that this needs to be run N times each time a user is updated.